# i get this error Procedure or function 'AddDepartment' expects parameter '@D_id', which was not supplied

Tags: c#

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDepartment]
    (
    @D_id int,
    @Catogery nvarchar(50),
    @viewcat int
    )

    AS
if(@D_id =-1)
    insert into Departments(Catogery, viewcat) values(@Catogery,@viewcat)
    else
    Update
    Departments set
    Catogery=@Catogery, viewcat= @viewcat where D_id=@D_id
```

Data access code:

```
public int AddDepartment(string D_id, string Catogery, string viewcat)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddDepartment", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catogery", Catogery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viewcat", viewcat);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D_id", D_id);

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That error occurs if an input value is `null`.  I would check each parameter value for null and use `DBNull.Value` if it is.

Comment: in your cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue() I would use some null coalese type checking / assignment are you familiar with how to do that..? for example `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catogery", Catogery ?? DBNull.Value);`

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure parameter is of type `int` whereas you have defined your `D_id` as string in your method. `AddiWithValue` uses type inference and that is why you are getting the error. You should use and `int` type parameter in your method or do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D_id", int.Parse(D_id));
```

See: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.ca/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html)

Other option is to explicitly define type like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@D_id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = D_id;
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@D_id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = int.Parse(D_id);
```

Comment: I would not consider it `Evil` Per say` however I would definitely ass some Coalescing assignment / checks six of 1 half dozen of the other ..

Comment: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String i get this error

Comment: @boraaihashim, are you sure you have some value in your string `D_id`, put a break point and see in debugger.

Comment: can you edit my funtion in correct sintax in this part of code

Comment: public int AddDepartment(string D_id, string Catogery, string viewcat)

Comment: @boraaihashim, I can definitely edit it, but then you will end up with another error in method call. Modifying this is not the point.  Make sure your string `D_Id`  has some value in it and read more about C#